# How can malware run on a pc when installed?

Tags: c++

I had a quick question. I was working on understanding malware and then I started to wonder how was malware able to run on its own when installed? So for example, I was to click on a bad link that someone sent me, the malware installs on my computer, but isn't that it...the file is installed but it can't run unless I click on the actual file itself.exe right? If that is the case then what is the worry about malware, as long as you don't run it then you're fine? I am currently working on c++ and working on creating a GUI and so I was trying to have a finished product of .exe and while learning about it, I have stumbled on some pretty interesting things I never even asked myself.

Comment: Here's some useful information for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+how+to+start+a+process+automatically&rlz=1C1CHBF_deDE833DE833&oq=windows+how+to+start+a+process+auto&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j33l4.25387j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: This is why Remote Code Execution (RCE) vulnerabilities are so scary. An RCE vuln means an outsider can "trick" your computer into executing foreign code without the computer user's permission or knowledge.

Comment: The recent trend for malware is to become "fileless" - they can execute inside and hijack a computer, without even needing to "drop" an executable file on the file system. They do this by exploiting RCE that allows them to inject themselves into the memory, and then resides in that memory until the computer reboots.

Comment: _"the file is installed but it can't run unless I click on the actual file itself.exe right?"_ This assumption is totally wrong. There are many ways how processes can be automatically started on a Windows PC without any user interaction.

Comment: @rwong but does this not imply like a script being ran? how does this even happen, how are they able to trick the computer into thinking that, im still lost at how this can be done without making a script run, i know im so dumb sorry

Comment: @Marstjugo _"but does this not imply like a script being ran?"_ Not necessarily.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it's not that the assumption is totally wrong. That's part of the security model. It's not wrong. It's simply often broken. Coders should try to enforce it. Outlook used to have a buffer overflow bug that only required you to check your mail. Someone sends you an email with more than 128 characters in the subject and outlook thinks the next 128 are executable code. Seems tiny but it was big enough to visit a C&C website and download the rest of the exploit. That wasn't the user misbehaving. That was Outlook misbehaving.

Comment: See also [What are the most common infection vectors for personal computers?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/17847/15930)

Comment: A computer OS has many task automations - scheduled tasks that will start at a specific time or when a event is triggered. Sometimes, just by placing a file inside a specific (system-only) folder is enough to get the file to execute at a specific time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> If that is the case then what is the worry about malware, as long as you don't run it then you're fine?

In theory, what you wrote is not completely wrong - browser and operating system vendors try to secure their systems in ways which make it impossible to let a program start (at least, not outside some sandbox) without explicit agreement of the user who sits in front of the machine.

However, browsers, operating systems and other programs which can be used (or abused) as a platform for program execution tend to have security leaks. And modern malware is trying to take advantage of these leaks before they get closed by the next software update. That's why [zero day exploits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploit_(computer_security)) are so dangerous, for which no fix is available at the time when some malware starts to "utilize" them.

For example, when you click at some link, this link might start some Javascript code inside the sandbox of your internet browser immediately (given you don't have some browser extension installed which prevents this). And when the Javascript engine has a bug, the malware may be able to break out of the sandbox, and run some code natively on the machine. Then that code could try to make use of more bugs for further [privilege escalation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privilege_escalation) to get administrative rights.

Once it has managed this, it can install itself in a way it will automatically start again secretly in the background, even when someone kills the process or restarts the machine.